# Detecting GUI state and generating user input programmatically in Windows Xp

Tags: windows, user-interface, macros, windows-xp

I am looking for a lightweight solution that would allow me to detect which form/ dialog is open in an application, then emit some keystrokes / mouse moves and clicks.  I do not have control over (nor the source-code for)  the application.

I am familiar with MacroMaker, also testing products like SQA / Mercury offer similar functionality.  The last time I had hands on exposure in this are is late 2004, I welcome any pointers to bring my knowledge up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody is curious, in the end I decided to use Microsoft UI Automation.  Here is nice intro:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163288.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is a scripting environment for Windows with a long history. It's quite easy to use and flexible to do things like detect the open window or dialog, change to another one, type something, etc. I would definitely recommend it.